# how to close previously opened shell chrome browser in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used the following javascript code to open chrome browser from the internet explorer

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function openChrome(){
        var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        var chromeCommand = "Chrome --app=http://www.google.com --allow-outdated-plugins";
        shell.run(chromeCommand);    
    }
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="openChrome()">
</body>
</html>
```

Here I need to close previously opened google chrome browser. How can I close previously opened chrome?

can we achieve with jquery?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
function closeChrome(){
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var chromeCommand = "taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T";
    shell.run(chromeCommand);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Help. It closes all instances of Google Chrome, is there any specific change will work to close Chrome opened from the IE.

Comment: I think it is not possible if you do not know the pid of the chrome window you want to close

Comment: Thanks for your help . We can close chrome by window title using this command taskkill /IM chrome.exe /FI \"WINDOWTITLE eq Google*\"

Comment: observed one issue with above command,the opened chrome browser not being close when it is in minimize